# PHP Soap Client how to handle complexTypes?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm currently writing a webservice and calling a function but that function only understands the first two parameters I use.

My function is supposed to add an entry with the data provided under the **addressData** parameter in the **campaignName** and will match the entry on the "addressId" parameter. The only thing I managed to do until now is inserting an empty entry with the correct **addressId** in the good **campaignName**.

Here's the description of the function:

```
<s:element name="ImportAddress">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="campaignName" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="addressId" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="addressData" type="tns:ArrayOfAddressDataItem"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Complex Type ArrayOfAddressDataItem:

```
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfAddressDataItem">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="AddressDataItem" nillable="true" type="tns:AddressDataItem"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

And complex type AddressDataItem

```
<s:complexType name="AddressDataItem">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="key" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="value" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

And here's my PHP Code:

This request call returns a success:

```
$arr_import_address_params = array(
    'campaignName' => 'TEST - Liste des concessions',
    'addressId' => $addressId,
    'addressData' => array(array(
        'Civilite' => 'XXX',
        'Code_postal' => 'XXX',
        'Creation_date' => 'XXX',
        'Email' => 'XXX',
        'Nom' => 'XXX',
        'Prenom' => 'XXX',
        'Telephone' => 'XXX',
        'Ville' => 'XXX',
    ))
);
```

As I said earlier, this success call inserts an empty entry with correct ID and campaignName.

But this one (which is supposed to be the correct one) returns an error:

```
$arr_import_address_params = array(
    'campaignName' => 'TEST - Liste des concessions',
    'addressId' => $addressId,
    'addressData' => array(
        array('key' => 'Civilite', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Code_postal', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Creation_date', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Email', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Nom', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Prenom', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Telephone', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Ville', 'value' => 'XXX'),
    )
);
```

That is the result of the second call:

object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
    ["ImportAddressResult"]=>
    string(9) "Exception"
  }

Which in the documentation means an unknown error occurred.

Here's how I make my request:

```
$options = array(
    "login" => "xxx",
    "password" => "xxx",
    "encoding" => "UTF-8",
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => 1
);

$client = new SoapClient("http://xxx/ImportExport/ImportExportWS.asmx?WSDL", $options);

$addressId = "TEST-WITH-UNEXISTING-ID";

$request_params = array(
    'campaignName' => 'TEST - Liste des concessions',
    'addressId' => $addressId,
    'addressData' => array(
        array('key' => 'Civilite', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Code_postal', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Creation_date', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Email', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Nom', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Prenom', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Telephone', 'value' => 'XXX'),
        array('key' => 'Ville', 'value' => 'XXX'),
    )
);

$request_result = $client->ImportAddress($request_params);
```

Example of request XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="xxx">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ImportAddress>
            <ns1:campaignName>TEST - Liste des concessions</ns1:campaignName>
            <ns1:addressId>TEST-UNIQUE-IDENTIFIER</ns1:addressId>
            <ns1:addressData>
                <ns1:AddressDataItem>
                    <ns1:key>Civilite</ns1:key>
                    <ns1:value>XXX</ns1:value>
                </ns1:AddressDataItem>
                <ns1:AddressDataItem>
                    <ns1:key>Code_postal</ns1:key>
                    <ns1:value>XXX</ns1:value>
                </ns1:AddressDataItem>
                <ns1:AddressDataItem>
                    <ns1:key>Creation_date</ns1:key>
                    <ns1:value>XXX</ns1:value>
                </ns1:AddressDataItem>
                <ns1:AddressDataItem>
                    <ns1:key>Email</ns1:key>
                    <ns1:value>XXX</ns1:value>
                </ns1:AddressDataItem>
                <ns1:AddressDataItem>
                    <ns1:key>Nom</ns1:key>
                    <ns1:value>XXX</ns1:value>
                </ns1:AddressDataItem>
                <ns1:AddressDataItem>
                    <ns1:key>Prenom</ns1:key>
                    <ns1:value>XXX</ns1:value>
                </ns1:AddressDataItem>
                <ns1:AddressDataItem>
                    <ns1:key>Telephone</ns1:key>
                    <ns1:value>XXX</ns1:value>
                </ns1:AddressDataItem>
                <ns1:AddressDataItem>
                    <ns1:key>Ville</ns1:key>
                    <ns1:value>XXX</ns1:value>
                </ns1:AddressDataItem>
            </ns1:addressData>
        </ns1:ImportAddress>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I wonder if I have a problem with the type I send?
I read somewhere I can use arrays instead of objects and it seems to work until it comes to the adressData parameter.

I don't know why I did anything wrong, I think my code follows the WSDL description but it seems I forgot something...

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Nathan

Comment: Could you try objects instead of arrays?

Comment: I will try that. Should I go with stdClass or class named as the WSDL?

Comment: I used C# instead of PHP.